# Binding VueJS data variable to iFrame src

Tags: vue.js, iframe, vuejs2, nuxt.js, youtube-iframe-api

I am using YouTube iFrame to embed YouTube player into my NuxtJS application. `videoId` is passed as property to the component. And then URL is constructed and returned as data property to `src` attribute of iFrame.

YoutubePlayer.vue

```
props: {
  videoId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
},
data() {
  return {
    videoUrl:
      "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" +
      this.videoId+
      "?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com"
  };
}

<template>
  <div class="iframeContainer">
    <iframe
      id="ytplayer"
      width="640"
      height="360"
      :src="videoUrl"
    ></iframe>
  </div>
</template>
```

But this is not working.  What am I doing wrong?
UPDATE:  No error in the console and nothing on the screen.

Comment: How is it not working? Any error in the console?

Comment: @YomS. see my update

Comment: @yom I am using the same syntax

Comment: Please do a jsfiddle and show us where or how exactly this is not working for you. Because I just tested and it worked fine for me. Dynamic URL binding on the `src` should not be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to check this?

```
props: {
  videoId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
},

data() {
  return {
    videoUrl: '',

  };
},

watch: {
  videoId: function(newVal) { 
     this.videoUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" +
         newVal +
         "?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com"
  }
}
```